# "equivalent" pronunciation of pairs of words

Tags: pronunciation

This ["The Langage Nerds" post](https://thelanguagenerds.com/54-clever-illustrations-of-words-that-sound-the-same-but-have-different-meanings/) illustrates many "same pronunciation different meaning" pairs of words.
While most seem reasonable to me, I'm surprised by some, and wonder if there is some USA's bias or if it's really once again all due to my bad pronunciation.

Typically, are these always pronounced the same ? or only in American English ? or nether ?

- hole / whole
- exercise / exorcise
- aisle / I'll / Isle
- affect / effect
- cereal / serial
- catch up / ketchup
- miner / minor
- lightening / lightning
- gorilla / guerrilla

Comment: In British English _ketchup_ is pronounced as spelled. All the rest, yes, although careful speakers might pronounce _exorcise_ and _guerrilla_ differently.

Comment: I am British, and I am careful about those, and also exercise, affect, lightening, and, yes, catch up (which is two words anyway)

Answer (score 1):

There certainly are a lot of homophones in English, though these are probably not the best selection: ones like bough/bow and ruff/rough are more interesting.

Here is a summary of my opinions as a UK English speaker.

**hole/whole**, **cereal/serial**, **minor/miner**, **gorilla/guerilla** and **aisle/isle** are identical when prounounced correctly.

**exercise/exorcise** and possibly **lightening/lightning** are similar in informal speech.

**I'll** is the same as **isle** when it is stressed, but when it is unstressed they are significantly different.

Listening to recordings of **catch up** and **ketchup** the phonemes are a lot closer than I expected, but the stress is usually on **ket** in **ketchup** and on **up** in **catch up**.

**affect/effect** are not the same under any circumstances.

Comment: As an AmE speaker, I pronounce **affect** and **effect** identically, except when **affect** used as a noun ("She shows an emotionless **affect**") and the first syllable is accented.

Comment: @CanadianYankee Yes, you are right.  According to the Cambridge Dictionary, the pronunciation of effect is UK /ɪˈfekt/ US  /əˈfekt/, and affect is  UK /əˈfekt/ US  /əˈfekt/, so affect and effect are identical in US pronunciation. Note that my answer relates only to the UK pronunciation.

Comment: Gorilla and guerilla are not identical when I say them, and I am a British RP speaker.

Comment: @MichaelHarvey According to the Cambridge Dictionary, the two words are /ɡəˈrɪl.ə/  /ɡəˈrɪl.ə/. I have noticed that some people with exposure to Spanish (the root language of guerilla) or to French  pronounce the first syllable with a Spanish accent  /ɡeˈrɪl.ə/

Comment: I say gorilla with the -or like horrible, Morris, and the -ue in guerilla like in puerile.